Garbled Circuit equivalency proof
What is the most efficient Garbled Circuit equivalency (two garbled circuits compute the same function) ZK-proof for Yao's circuit till date? ZK-SNARK might help but the sheer size of increased circuit gates (hashing labels) and encryption (even if just XOR) for each binary gate in original circuit, means it might not be the most efficient solution. I have tried looking at Google Scholar but I cannot find anything either. A link to a paper would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: Since I cannot find an answer, an alternative question. Is there is a way to mass-produce garbled circuits with small proof overhead, all that compute the same function, but secure enough to use as if they were produced independently?
